# No visible @interface for reachability declares the selector startNotifier

Tags: ios, reachability

i get this error: No visible @interface for reachability declares the selector startNotifier

i have included both Reachability.h and .m files.
i am extremely new to objective-C and the error might be really tiny! but any help would be great!

my helloworldViewController.m

```
#import "helloworldViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>


@interface helloworldViewController ()

@end

@implementation helloworldViewController
@synthesize networkstatus;
@synthesize reach;



#pragma mark Reachability changed


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Check network
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    self.reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
    [self.reach startNotifer];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
    Reachability* r = [note object];
    NetworkStatus ns = r.currentReachabilityStatus;

    if (ns == NotReachable)
    {
        NSString* msg = @"Network problems have rendered the iTunes store inaccessible; please try again later.";
        UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                     message:msg
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [av show];
        //[av release];
    }
}


@end
```

and here is my helloworldViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface helloworldViewController : UIViewController{


    Reachability* reach;
    IBOutlet UILabel *networkstatus;

}
@property(strong,nonatomic) UILabel *networkstatus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Reachability* reach;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spelled the method incorrectly. Change this line:

```
[self.reach startNotifer];
```

to:

```
[self.reach startNotifier];
```

Since you are new, here are a few more suggestions:

- Replace `#import "Reachability.h"` in the .h file with `@class Reachability`.
- Get rid of the explicit ivars and the explicit `@synthesize` lines. Let the compiler generate these for you. This assumes you are using the latest compiler/Xcode.
- You are being inconsistent in your properties. One is `strong` and the other is `retain`. If you are using ARC, use `strong` for both. If you are using MRC, using `retain` for both.
- It is standard convention that class names begin with uppercase letters and methods and variables begin with lowercase. Both should use CamelCase. Change your class to `HelloWorldViewController`. Change `networkstatus` to `networkStatus`.